# cannot obtain all dimensions with FactoMiner

Tags: r, pca

I am performing a PCA analysis with FactoMiner with 7 variables, and having these results with 7 dimensions to account for 100% of variation:
Eigenvalues

```
                       Dim.1   Dim.2   Dim.3   Dim.4   Dim.5   Dim.6   Dim.7
Variance               2.482   1.445   1.223   0.944   0.619   0.193   0.095
% of var.             35.453  20.636  17.471  13.484   8.838   2.754   1.364
Cumulative % of var.  35.453  56.090  73.561  87.045  95.882  98.636 100.000
```

However, when I call `summary(pca_pa, ncp=7)` it does not give me results of the contribution of each variable upto 7 dimensions but only maximum 5 dimensions.
For example, this is what I get for contributions of each variable for1st three dimensions:

```
Variables
                   Dim.1    ctr   cos2    Dim.2    ctr   cos2    Dim.3    ctr
b_0             | -0.007  0.002  0.000 |  0.133  1.229  0.018 |  0.857 60.111
v_X             |  0.308  3.815  0.095 |  0.034  0.078  0.001 | -0.625 31.897
W_M             | -0.737 21.884  0.543 |  0.561 21.761  0.314 | -0.204  3.407
v_Y             | -0.016  0.011  0.000 | -0.858 50.958  0.736 |  0.116  1.092
v_F             |  0.940 35.586  0.883 | -0.004  0.001  0.000 | -0.058  0.278
v_P             |  0.922 34.228  0.849 |  0.220  3.364  0.049 |  0.043  0.150
v_L             |  0.333  4.474  0.111 |  0.571 22.609  0.327 |  0.194  3.066
```

I would like to have this table for all 7 dimensions. Would you please help me?
Thanks!

Phuong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you:

```
summary(pca_pa, ncp=7, nbelements=Inf)
```

The `nbelements` option is the number of written columns. It is `10` by default.

Comment: Hi Pop, the command "nbelement = Inf" if to call results for all individuals ( I have 102 repetitions for each variable). What I would like to have is 7 collummes of resullts equally to the atble above. In fact, when I try ncp =2, 3,4,5 it gives me results of 2,3,4,5 dimensions. But when I try ncp >=6, does not give more.

Comment: What is the value of `pca_pa$call$ncp` ?

Comment: Oops, it is "5". But why in the eigenvalue table it shows that to obtain 100% of variation, it is needed 7 dimensions? May you please explain this?

Comment: I have 3 questions. You did obtain pca_pa by typing `PCA(yourdata,ncp=7)` ? What is the value of `nrow(yourdata)` ? What is the value of  `nrow(yourdata)` ? `you_data` being the object on what you applied the pca.

Comment: I have 7 continous variables: bo, WM, vx. vy, vF, vP and vL, and these 7 variables are repeated 102 times, meaning that I have 102 rows. Also, these 102 rows are grouped by three breeds (A,B,C).

Comment: Hi Po, I tried you comments on [PCA(data, ncp=7), and it worked, I did not specify ncp in the command of PCA before. Sorry and thanks very much!

Comment: Indeed, the default value for `ncp` is `5`.